# PHP in HTML: how to

Tags: php

I made a PHP script for a form, but dont't know how to get it to work...How do i put the PHP in the page and make it active? I am a total noob to php, so i have no idea. Do you put the php inside the HTML doc, or make a separate PHP document and link to that?
The PHP thing is here, in case you need it.

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'youremail@site.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form '; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["comment"])."<br>"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>
```

Comment: This needs a form to be posted to it.  `<form action="test.php" method="POST">`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be to create a separate PHP page (e.g. send.php) and then have the form in your HTML page use it in the action attribute (e.g. `<form method="post" action="send.php">`)

Answer (score -3):

put it at the top of the .php file which contains the html code if you want it to work